# How do I extract multiple values of a 3D array from coordinates stored in a matrix on R?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, coordinates, extract

```
head(prewind)
     column row   ALARM_DATE         day    
[1,] "189"  "404" "24/01/1990 00:00" " 24"
[2,] "189"  "404" "24/01/1990 00:00" " 24"
[3,] "189"  "404" "24/01/1990 00:00" " 24"
[4,] "189"  "404" "24/01/1990 00:00" " 24"
[5,] "189"  "404" "24/01/1990 00:00" " 24"
[6,] "189"  "404" "24/01/1990 00:00" " 24"
```

The indices I would like to enter are from 'column', 'row' and 'day' which would be entered into:

```
tmp.array[column,row,day]
```

to return a wind speed value.
I would like to enter these values going down each row of the matrix and return a dataframe/matrix of all the wind values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the column, row, 'day' are 'character', we need to first convert it to numeric

```
ind <- prewind[, c('col', 'row', 'day')]
ind[] <- as.numeric(ind)
tmp.array[ind]
```

Comment: I tried:   ind <- prewind[, c('column', 'row', 'day')]     however it says it could not find function 'prewind' or that 'subscript out of bounds'

Comment: @TomShelton  I thought your object name is `prewind`.  Is it `head` (which is also a function name)

Comment: apologies - it should be head(prewind) - the matrix below is the head of prewind

Comment: @TomShelton okay,then it should work because I  assume these are column names

Comment: ah it has worked now thanks but on the last step 'tmp.array[ind]' it says negative values are not allowed in a matrix subscript?

Comment: @TomShelton  Can you check the output of `ind` as I don't have a rperoducible example

Comment: head(ind) shows a matrix with headings column, row and day, however when I do tmp.array[ind] it says 'error in tmp.array[ind] : subscript out of bounds'

Comment: @TomShelton  It could be that some of the index are not there in the 'tmp.array'  Let me create a reproducible example to test my code

Comment: @TomShelton Are you  sure that the order of index aree right i.e. should it be `c('row', 'column', 'day')`

Comment: the headings are 'column' 'row' and 'day' in that order, is it because there are speech marks around each value in the 'ind' matrix? - ie each value is "280" etc

Comment: It is actually checking for the position `189, 404, 24` Are you able extract `prewind[189, 404, 24]`

Comment: As in by inputting tmp.array[189, 404, 24]? If so yes it gives a wind speed of 3.2 m/s

Comment: I have just reentered everything - including the last step tmp.array[ind] and it comes back with: numeric(0) - what does this mean??

Comment: @TomShelton let's say you are doing this in a `loop`  i.e. `for(i in seq_len(nrow(ind))) print(tmp.array[ind[i, 1], ind[i, 2], ind[i, 3]])` do you find any cases which it doesn't work

Comment: @TomShelton it means the index is out of bound as your original data 'prewind' doesn't have that dimension

Comment: so if I have got a matrix of coordinates as you discussed above, and I want to automate each of these to be inputted into tmp.array[ , , ] what is best to do? apologies I don't understand what you meant above?

Comment: @TomShelton   I guess you posted a new  question with similar info.

Comment: sorry yes I feel I worded it poorly so it was hard for you to understand what I meant? does it help anymore?

Comment: @TomShelton I think  I would use the same answer from the info you showed